# Reading Json in webservice Rest in Android. FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, json, web-services, rest, filenotfoundexception

Someone know why not works this json in android? [urlJson](http://www.pablogeek.com/webservices/rest/milanuncios/categorias)

Result is  FileNotFoundException, but on the navigator works.

**edit:**

```
public static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try{
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (url.openStream()));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int read;
            char[]chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

            return buffer.toString();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BufferedReader is not the best method to do this task.
Is a lot better use HttpClient with following sample using the library org.json.*;

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.*****.com/json");

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
        String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        JSONArray respJSON = new JSONArray(respStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The format is wrong.
Use {"name": "string", "...": "..."}

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I'm using spring and I removed this in the service

```
@RequestMapping(value="/categorias", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Portada getCategorias() {
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value="/categorias", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Portada getCategorias() {
```

Now works!