# FileNotFound Exception when getting JSON from a REST server in Android

Tags: android, json, rest

I have a problem getting the `JSON` data from the REST server. The web browser returns the `JSON` data [here](http://eventoserver-ecinauce.rhcloud.com/songwol/services) correctly, but the code below would cause a `FileNotFound` Exception:

```
    private void getJSON(String url) {
    class GetJSONServices extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = new ProgressDialog(ServicesActivity.this);
            loading.setTitle("");
            loading.setMessage("Getting your services...");
            loading.setCancelable(false);
            loading.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String uri = params[0];

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(uri);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String json;
                while((json = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                    sb.append(json+"\n");
                }

                return sb.toString().trim();

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Do In Background", getStackTrace(e));
                return null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            loading.dismiss();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                Toast.makeText(ServicesActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("On Post Execute", getStackTrace(e));
            }

        }
    }
    GetJSONServices gj = new GetJSONServices();
    gj.execute(url);
}
```

Also, the AndroidManifest.xml has the INTERNET permission, and the REST server allows CORS. What caused this error and how do I fix it?

Edit: I'm using HttpURLConnection, not the removed HttpClient.

Comment: What is the output of `sb.toString()` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Json in webservice Rest in Android. FileNotFoundException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978412/reading-json-in-webservice-rest-in-android-filenotfoundexception)

Answer (score 0):

I am using `commons.io.2.4` library in this example,

Apparently i am not getting the error as you can see the output,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://eventoserver-ecinauce.rhcloud.com/songwol/services");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        String result = IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(""+result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

> Output

```
{
  "3": {
    "id": 3,
    "info": null,
    "name": "singer",
    "owner": 1,
    "packages": {},
    "reviews": {},
    "type": "performer"
  }
}
```